# Debian Wheezy wireless wont accept password

Tags: wireless-networking, gnome3, debian-wheezy

I have upgraded from Squeeze to Wheezy. . When I enter the wireless password, It is not accepted. I can connect on other devices. I am not sure how to find out where the fault lies.

card: 04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network

Wireless connection type is WEP 128bit.

```
lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
ip6table_filter        12540  0 
ip6_tables             22175  1 ip6table_filter
iptable_filter         12536  0 
ip_tables              22042  1 iptable_filter
x_tables               19073  4 ip_tables,iptable_filter,ip6_tables,ip6table_filter
cpufreq_conservative    13147  0 
cpufreq_powersave      12454  0 
cpufreq_stats          12866  0 
cpufreq_userspace      12576  0 
parport_pc             22364  0 
ppdev                  12763  0 
lp                     17149  0 
parport                31858  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
bnep                   17567  2 
rfcomm                 33656  0 
bluetooth             119406  10 rfcomm,bnep
crc16                  12343  1 bluetooth
binfmt_misc            12957  1 
uinput                 17440  0 
nfsd                  211858  2 
nfs                   312243  0 
nfs_acl                12511  2 nfs,nfsd
auth_rpcgss            37143  2 nfs,nfsd
fscache                36739  1 nfs
lockd                  67328  2 nfs,nfsd
sunrpc                173671  6 lockd,auth_rpcgss,nfs_acl,nfs,nfsd
loop                   22641  0 
fuse                   61981  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   188797  1 
pcmcia                 32691  0 
arc4                   12458  2 
snd_hda_intel          26345  2 
snd_hda_codec          78031  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              13186  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                63900  2 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
ath9k                  73540  0 
snd_page_alloc         13003  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
ath9k_common           12728  1 ath9k
snd_seq                45093  0 
snd_seq_device         13176  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              22917  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
yenta_socket           22899  0 
iTCO_wdt               17081  0 
r592                   17835  0 
pcmcia_rsrc            17533  1 yenta_socket
joydev                 17266  0 
acpi_cpufreq           12935  1 
ath9k_hw              317921  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
i915                  356043  3 
uvcvideo               57744  0 
videodev               70889  1 uvcvideo
drm_kms_helper         27227  1 i915
ath                    21370  3 ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,ath9k
drm                   167670  4 drm_kms_helper,i915
mac80211              192768  1 ath9k
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    16655  1 videodev
media                  18148  2 videodev,uvcvideo
snd                    52850  12 snd_timer,snd_seq_device,snd_seq,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
iTCO_vendor_support    12704  1 iTCO_wdt
coretemp               12898  0 
mperf                  12453  1 acpi_cpufreq
asus_laptop            18484  0 
cfg80211              137140  3 mac80211,ath,ath9k
i2c_algo_bit           12841  1 i915
memstick               13698  1 r592
pcmcia_core            18294  3 pcmcia_rsrc,yenta_socket,pcmcia
battery                13109  0 
psmouse                64455  0 
i2c_core               23876  5 i2c_algo_bit,drm,drm_kms_helper,videodev,i915
soundcore              13065  1 snd
sparse_keymap          12760  1 asus_laptop
rfkill                 19012  6 cfg80211,asus_laptop,bluetooth
input_polldev          12906  1 asus_laptop
pcspkr                 12579  0 
serio_raw              12931  0 
ac                     12624  0 
evdev                  17562  14 
processor              28157  3 acpi_cpufreq
power_supply           13475  2 ac,battery
button                 12937  1 i915
video                  17628  1 i915
ext3                  161867  1 
mbcache                13065  1 ext3
jbd                    56902  1 ext3
sg                     25874  0 
sr_mod                 21899  0 
sd_mod                 36136  3 
crc_t10dif             12348  1 sd_mod
cdrom                  35401  1 sr_mod
ata_generic            12479  0 
8139too                26492  0 
thermal                17383  0 
8139cp                 22699  0 
mii                    12675  2 8139cp,8139too
ata_piix               29535  0 
thermal_sys            18040  3 thermal,video,processor
ahci                   24997  2 
libahci                22860  1 ahci
sdhci_pci              17976  0 
sdhci                  27053  1 sdhci_pci
mmc_core               72460  2 sdhci,sdhci_pci
uhci_hcd               26865  0 
libata                140589  4 libahci,ahci,ata_piix,ata_generic
ehci_hcd               40215  0 
scsi_mod              162372  4 libata,sd_mod,sr_mod,sg
usbcore               128498  4 ehci_hcd,uhci_hcd,uvcvideo
usb_common             12354  1 usbcore
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the wrong driver is being loaded.  What does lsmod say?

Just a side note, WEP is not very secure due to the static keys it uses.  Have you thought about using WPA2?

Comment: Will look into it...see edit

Comment: ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,ath9k  are the Atheros drivers.  My TP-LINK adapter uses the same modules.  Take a look at this post, it may point you in the right direction: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5711824&postcount=6

Comment: The problem seems to be with connections that are added, the connection I had before I 'upgraded' are OK